# How to use Array.Contains in razorpages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm currently having a problem using Contains inside cshtml file.
I want to check if `devgroup` contains a `user`.

```
@{ 
                                    string[] devgroup = { "55", "53", "75" };
                                    var devdisplay = "none";
                                    var user = ViewBag.IDEmployee;
                                    if (devgroup.Contains(user))
                                    {
                                        devdisplay = "block";
                                    }

                                }
```

and I'm currently having an compile error.

```
Error   CS1929  'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'MemoryExtensions.Contains<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T>, T)' requires a receiver of type 'ReadOnlySpan<T>'
```

Comment: Maybe you need [`Array.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?view=net-6.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You List in this case like below

```
@{
        List<string> devgroup = new List<string>(){ "55", "53", "75" };
        var devdisplay = "none";
        var user = ViewBag.IDEmployee;
        if (devgroup.Contains(user))
        {
            devdisplay = "block";
        }

    }
```

or

```
@{
        List<string> devgroup = new List<string>(){ "55", "53", "75" };
        var devdisplay = "none";
        var user = ViewBag.IDEmployee;
        if (if (Array.Exists(devgroup,(i)=> i==user))
        {
            devdisplay = "block";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
if (devgroup.ToList().Any(d=>d==user))
```

or

```
if (devgroup.ToList().Contains(user))
```